# How to use rootBundle in flutter to load images?

Tags: image, dart, flutter

I use image plugin (**image: ^2.0.4**) so I can write something on to the image and later save it new image to device or send via mail. I try to load image using "**new File**" but got error on Flutter. I ask and search and got a hint that I can use rootBundle to load image in Flutter. I did, and I got this below error.

> [ERROR:topaz/lib/tonic/logging/dart_error.cc(16)] Unhandled exception:
>    Unable to load asset: packages/myAppName/assets/images/ReceiptRaw_1.jpg

The plugin works when I create a simple dart console app, but couldn't load  using flutter. Any help please,

**This is the Flutter Code:**

```
    Future<bool> makeReceiptImage() async {

// UPDATE ****************************************

      // load the receipt jpeg
  var imageData = await rootBundle.load('packages/myAppName/dekonts/ReceiptRaw_1.jpg');
  print("imageData: $imageData"); // Prints as imageData: Instance of 
'_ByteDataView'

// UPDATE ****************************************

  Image _receiptImage = await decodeImage(new File(imageData).readAsBytesSync());

      drawString(_receiptImage, arial_48, 440, 30, “Customer Name”, color: 0xFF000000); 

      // Write it to disk as a different jpeg 
      var new_jpeg = await encodeJpg(_receiptImage); 
      String newImagePath = await rootBundle.loadString('packages/myAppName/assets/images/ReceiptRaw_2.jpg'); 
      await new File(‘$newImagePath’).writeAsBytesSync(new_jpeg); 
    }
```

**This is the Dart Console Code:**

```
import 'dart:io';
import 'dart:convert';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:image/image.dart';

void main() async {
  // load the receipt jpeg
  String mImagePath = 'images/ReceiptRaw_1.jpg';
  Image _receiptImage = decodeImage(new File(mImagePath).readAsBytesSync());
  drawString(_receiptImage, arial_48, 440, 30, “Customer Name”, color: 0xFF000000);

  // Write it to disk as a different jpeg
  var new_jpeg = encodeJpg(_receiptImage);
  new File('images/ReceiptRaw_1.jpg').writeAsBytesSync(new_jpeg);
}
```

**Update-1:**
When I use below code I get en error as:

> Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
>   *No file or variants found for asset: packages/myAppName/assets/images/ReceiptRaw_1.jpg*

```
 String imageData = await rootBundle.loadString('packages/myAppName/assets/images/ReceiptRaw_1.jpg');
  Image _receiptImage = await decodeImage(new File(imageData).readAsBytesSync());
```

**Update-2:**
if I use `rootBundle.load` I got below error.

> Error: A value of type 'dart.typed_data::ByteData' can't be assigned to a variable of type 'dart.core::String'.

```
var imageData = await rootBundle.load('packages/myAppName/assets/images/ReceiptRaw_1.jpg');
  Image _receiptImage = await decodeImage(new File(imageData).readAsBytesSync());
```

**New Update:**

**Step 1:**
Move to `ReceiptRaw_1.jpg` into `lib/dekonts/` folder

**Change to:**

```
assets:
  - packages/myAppName/dekonts/ReceiptRaw_1.jpg
```

**Change to:**

```
var imageData = await rootBundle.load('packages/myAppName/dekonts/ReceiptRaw_1.jpg');
print("imageData: $imageData");
```

**Result:** Prints as

> imageData: Instance of '_ByteDataView'

**Step 2:**
**Move to** `/lib/assets/images/ReceiptRaw_1.jpg` folder

**Change to:**

```
assets:
  - packages/myAppName/lib/assets/images/ReceiptRaw_1.jpg
```

**Change to:**

```
var imageData = await rootBundle.load('packages/myAppName/lib/assets/images/ReceiptRaw_1.jpg');
print("imageData: $imageData");
```

**Result:**  Got Error as:

> Resolving dependencies...
>   Running 'gradlew assembleDebug'...
>   Error detected in pubspec.yaml:
>   No file or variants found for asset: packages/myAppName/lib/assets/images/ReceiptRaw_1.jpg

Update:

> /// To include, say the first image, the `pubspec.yaml` of the app should
>   /// specify it in the assets section:
>   ///
>   ///  assets:
>   ///    - packages/fancy_backgrounds/backgrounds/background1.png
>   ///
>   /// The **`lib/` is implied**, so it should not be included in the asset  path.

Comment: `imageData` is already the image data. `new File(...).readAsBytesSync()` is redundant.

Comment: "No file or variants found for asset: packages/capitalbankmobile/assets/images/ReceiptRaw_1.jpg" Where do you have this file?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The files of pub dependencies are not available as files. They are contained in an archive file.

Add the image to assets in `pubspec.yaml`

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - packages/myAppName/assets/images/ReceiptRaw_1.jpg
```

then load it with

```
var imageData = await rootBundle.load('packages/myAppName/assets/images/ReceiptRaw_1.jpg');
```

For this to work the file `ReceiptRaw_1.jpg` needs to be in

```
myAppName/lib/assets/images/ReceiptRaw_1.jpg
```

Where the `lib/` part is mandatory.

Comment: Thank you very much, once I finished whole project I will post the working code as update.

Comment: Sounds great :)

Comment: I write to device using path_provider. But I cant read my image using

Comment: @Günther // Show the writen image
    if (_dekontExist == true){
      setState(() {
         newDekontImage = _appDocumentsDirectory + "/" + widget._currentUserReceiptNo + ".jpg";
      });

Comment: body: new Column(
        children: <Widget>[
          new Padding(
            padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0),
            child: Image.network("${newDekontImage}"+"?raw=true"),
          ),
        ],
      ),

Comment: Better use `Image.file(File('/data/user/0/com.mayapp.mayapp/app_flutter/20180700087.jpg'))`

Comment: This answer still didn't work for me . I have put my assets/lang/en.json inside core/lib/ folder and calling loadString('packages/core/assets/lang/en.js') but it says no such file . Any fix ? I have included packages/core/assets/lang/  in pubspec also :(

Comment: Perhaps an issue with indentation in pubspec.yaml. Try an online yaml validator.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer pubspec is valid : see this question https://stackoverflow.com/q/60144352/6665568

Comment: hi, if I want to load url, can I use this method?

Comment: @qing can you please elaborate? What url are you talking about?

Comment: ohh, I ask can use rootBundle.load to load network image or not

Comment: @qing nom rootBundle is for images bundled with your app at build time. You can use the NetworkImage widget or Image with the Image.network constructor (if I remember correctly) or use an HTTP request if you need the image in memory without immediately rendering it.

Answer (score 2):

With @Günter Zöchbauer help, I finally made it. My small contribution to Stack Overflow members.

**// TODO: 1 - LOAD EVERYTHING**

```
  Future _loadEverything() async {
    await _requestAppDocumentsDirectory();   // TODO: 2 - GET APP DOCUMENTS DIRECTORY
    _dekontExist = await makeReceiptImage(); // TODO: 3 - MAKE A RECEIPT

    // Show the writen image
    if (_dekontExist == true) {
      setState(() {
        newDekontImage = _appDocumentsDirectory + "/" + widget._currentUserReceiptNo + ".jpg";
        imageOkay = true; // FOR - 4 - MAIN WIDGET BUILD
      });
    }
  }
```

**// TODO: 2 - GET APP DOCUMENTS DIRECTORY**

```
Future _requestAppDocumentsDirectory() async {
  // I choose temp dir because I don’t want to write twice same Receipt
  // Also when user close the app it will destroys the images
  final _directory =
      await getTemporaryDirectory(); //getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
  setState(() {
    _appDocumentsDirectory = _directory.path;
  });
}
```

**// TODO: 3 - MAKE A RECEIPT**

```
Future<bool> makeReceiptImage() async {

  // I use this as a template:
  // 'packages/mayApp/assets/images/CapitalReceipt.jpg'  

  ByteData imageData = await rootBundle.load('packages/mayApp/assets/images/CapitalReceipt.jpg');
  List<int> bytes = Uint8List.view(imageData.buffer);
  Image _receiptImage = decodeImage(bytes);

  // TODO: WRITE ON TO THE IMAGE
  drawString(_receiptImage, arial_48, 440, 30, “Customer Receipt - Customer Name”, color: 0xFF000000);


  // Write it to disk as a different jpeg
    var new_jpeg = await encodeJpg(_receiptImage);
    String newDekontImage = _appDocumentsDirectory + "/" + "${_currentUserReceiptNo}" + ".jpg";
    await new File(newDekontImage).writeAsBytesSync(new_jpeg);

  return true;
}
```

**// TODO: 4 - MAIN WIDGET BUILD**

```
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    capitalHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    capitalWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    if (imageOkay == true) {
      return new Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
        appBar: new AppBar(
          title: new Text("Customer Receipt"),
          backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF7CB342),
          elevation: 0.0,
          actions: <Widget>[
            new Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
              child: new Icon(Icons.mail),
            )
          ],
        ),
        body: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new Padding(
              padding: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0),
              child: new Center(
                child: new Container(
                  width: capitalWidth,
                  height: capitalHeight / 2.3,
                  color: Colors.black54, //capitalLightGreen,
                  child: new Container(
                    width: capitalWidth - 20.0,
                    height: capitalHeight / 2.3,
                    child: Image.file(File('$newDekontImage')),
                  )
                ),
              )
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    } else {
      return new Scaffold(
          resizeToAvoidBottomPadding: true,
          appBar: new AppBar(
            title: new Text("Customer Receipt"),
            backgroundColor: const Color(0xFF7CB342),
            elevation: 0.0,
            actions: <Widget>[
              new Container(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(right: 10.0),
                child: new Icon(Icons.mail),
              )
            ],
          ),
          body: new Center(
            child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),
          ));
    }
  }
```

Comment: At first glance this looks way helpful, but when I try to reproduce this work, I get a whole lot of errors (45 errors). Yes, we all wish there was an easy way to jsFiddle a playground to test out flutter code concepts.  In the meantime we submit snippets into the 'hello world + button indicator" sample in build and test code.  And with that start, your code (as currently written) is a fail.  Perhaps you could add a bit (or even post up a functional example on your github repo?)

Comment: Hi, @zipzit I use image plugin (image: ^2.0.4). Everything you need in plugin example. I just modified with above code so it can work in Flutter. But I will try to make working example in GitHub so everyone can share. Thanks