# How to load a file from a specific package in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, flutter-dependencies

Here's my folder structure for the package `core` :

```
/pubspec.yaml
/assets
   |-images
   |-lang
       |- en.json
       |- hi.json
```

I have a similar structure for another module called `moduleA`

Now when I load the json file I load it like so :

```
    await rootBundle.loadString('assets/lang/en.json');
```

But issue is that when I use the screens of 'core' module in 'moduleA' , 'core' module looks inside the 'moduleA' to search for the filepath. What I need is a way to specify which package to load the file from :

Now I have already looked into the answer for the blow question and tried it but it didn't work for me:

[How to use rootBundle in flutter to load images?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51609421/how-to-use-rootbundle-in-flutter-to-load-images)

doing a rootBundle.loadString('packages/core/assets/lang/en.json') still gives me a file not found error despite having specified it in the pubspec.yaml file and copying the assets/ folder inside the core/lib folder.

So , when I load the String using :

```
await rootBundle.loadString('packages/core/assets/lang/${locale.languageCode}.json');
```

I am getting the following error :

```
Error: unable to find directory entry in pubspec.yaml: /Users/nateshmbhat/Desktop/nuclei-flutter-sdk/core/packages/core/assets/images/
```

Here is my core/pubspec.yaml content :

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - packages/core/assets/lang/
    - packages/core/assets/images/
```

I have moved the assets folder into core/lib/ .

Is there anything wrong I am doing here ? Any idea how to fix this ?

Comment: assets needs to be `lib/assets`

Comment: did you get solution for this?

Comment: yes see the answer below

Answer (score 4):

when building a package:

- put your assets in the assets folder of the package as usual
- add the `assets/translations/` to pubspec, don't forget the last / as it means the whole dir
- when using `rootBundle.loadAsString` or the likes the path will be `packages/package_name/assets/translations/en.json`. Note that `packages` is plural.

Answer (score -1):

Turned out that when we import assets inside packages , we need to include specific files too and just a folder include doesn't work.

So doing the following fixed it :D

```
flutter:
  assets:
    - packages/core/assets/lang/en.json
    - packages/core/assets/lang/sp.json
    - packages/core/assets/images/myimage.png
```

Comment: i have project with language json files and it wokking with just defining lang folders under assets without files path

Comment: this is not true