# is it possible to load string config from dependencies package assets in flutter

Tags: flutter

I am using this code to load some config from assets file in flutter:

```
  final jsonStr =
      await rootBundle.loadString("assets/emoji-flags.json", cache: false);
```

it works fine when reading the current project config file, I was wondering is it possible to read the config file from specifying package from pubspec.yaml dependencies? I want to move some config into some public dependencies that I could use in a different project. That would make me config for one and did not need to import and configure for every single project. BTW, I have read the source code of `rootBundle.loadString` and did not found the api to specify the package name as a parameter would do this task.

Answer (score 2):

Add `packages/{packagename}/` before path

```
    final data = await rootBundle.loadString(
        'packages/{packagename}/assets/emoji-flags.json"',
        cache: true);
```